# How can I get a column from a 2D python array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to know the co

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,0,0,2,3,0],[3,2,4,0,0,1]])
```

If I want to get col2 to col4, so result may be:

```
[[0,2,3][4,0,0]]
```

How can I make it? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think that [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) there is almost all you need about numpy slicing

Comment: Besides: your title and your question don't match. Fix either one or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[0,0,0,2,3,0],[3,2,4,0,0,1]])
>>> a[:,2:5]
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 0]])
```